# how to compare key in foreach array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm working with laravel. Today, I try to compare key from index of array.My array is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 17
            [count] => 5.5
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 6
            [count] => 5.5
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 30
            [count] => 5.0
        )
)
```

I has using foreach syntax:

```
$index=0;
foreach($data as $key) {
$i = index++;
    if($key[$index]->count == $key[$i++]->count) {  // or $key->{$index}->count == $key->{$index++}->count
        echo 'done';
    }
    $index++;
}
```

But i'm getting error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`. What can I do, anyone?

Comment: What exactly you want to compare and to what you want to compare?

Comment: I want to do ranking for user @RohitAwasthi

Comment: you need to compare every count with all other counts and then create ranking? if so then this loop is wrong. And just for the error you are getting it is because you are using `$key[$index]->count` instead you should use `$key->count`

Comment: That's problem fixed by @cresjie show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
foreach($data as $i => $object){
    if( isset($data[$i+1]) && ($object->count == $data[$i+1]->count) ) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$key` is

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 17
        [count] => 5.5
    )
```

You can't do `$key[$index]`.

You don't seem to need `$index`; if you did, you would have wanted:

```
foreach ($data as $index => $object)
```

Comment: I know I can't do `$key[$index]` in this case.But I want to compare, this is problem! @amadan

Comment: My bad, you do need the index. You should use the bottom form of `foreach`, like cresjie shows.